# How to save gravity forms total pricing value in database

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am working on `gravity forms` add-on. I am saving all the values of gform fields in my database successfully after form submission using this hook `gform_after_submission`. Now I want to save the total pricing value but I don't get it I also see that the total pricing value coming from span.

So i search a lot but nothing found except some java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId) {
        return total;
     } );

</script>
```

But i don't get that how can i get this value in `gform_after_submission` hook

So please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 2):

check bellow code . it's meet your requirement  .

```
 function saiful_gf_remove_money_symbol( $s ) {
    return GFCommon::to_number( $s );
}
add_filter( 'saiful_gf_remove_money_symbol', 'saiful_gf_remove_money_symbol' ); 
add_filter( 'gform_product_info', 'add_fee', 10, 3 );
function add_fee( $product_info, $form, $lead ) {
    $loop_price = 0;
    if( isset( $product_info['products'] ) && count( $product_info['products'] ) > 0 ){
        foreach ( $product_info['products'] as $data ){
            if( isset( $data['options'] ) && count( $data['options'] ) > 0 ){
            foreach ( $data['options'] as $key => $option ) {
                $loop_price += floatval( $option['price'] );
            }
            }
            // Save From Here total amount
            $new_price = apply_filters( 'saiful_gf_remove_money_symbol',$data['price']) + $loop_price ;
        }
    }
    return $product_info;
}
```